# Need to show the time between case status change using trigger?

Tags: case

I need to catch the time when a case status is changed from one status to another. like a case is in new status now its change to working or a case is in working and when it is changed  to escalated . I want the time between one case status to another . please Help me, How can i achieve this task???

I have written a trigger.. But there is some mistake i could not find... please Help me and modify the error.

I create an Object: CaseStatusDuration
Three fields are there:
1>currStat
2>casNum
3>Duration__c(Field Type:Date/Time)

When a case status will change then the Duration between two status will be save to that object CaseStatusDuration in Duration field.

```
trigger statusUpdateTrigger1 on Case (after update) {
List<Case> cases = new List<Case>(trigger.new);

        for(Case c : cases)
            {


                if(c.status != trigger.oldMap.get(c.id).status){
                   DateTime d1=c.CreatedDate;

                  DateTime d2=c.LastModifiedDate;
                   decimal Hours = decimal.valueOf((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()));
                   decimal hour1 = Hours/(1000*60*60);

                   Integer min1 = Integer.valueOf(Hours/(1000*60));
                   min1=math.mod(min1,60);


                   String str1=String.valueOf(hour1);
                   string[] str2=str1.split('\\.');
                   string hour=str2[0];
                   string min=string.valueOf(min1);

                   String currStat=c.Status;
                   String casNum=c.CaseNumber;
                   CaseStatusDuration__c obj =new CaseStatusDuration__c();
                   obj.Duration__c=hour+':'+min;

                   obj.casNum=c.caseNumber;
                   obj.Status__c=currStat;

                   insert obj;

                   }
            }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would need a trigger for this. I think workflow rules would work just fine.

We created date/time fields for each of our statuses for reporting on time between each status. You could create the same for each of yours.

After the fields are created, create your workflow rules to capture the change in status. When the status equals the value you want, populate the respective date/time field with Now().

---

Edit to include code, since I am unsure of how to format the comment to show this.

This is the part of the link in the comment below that shows how to track days, hours, and minutes.

```
IF(
  Diff_c > 0 ,
  TEXT( FLOOR( Diff_c ) ) & " days "
  & TEXT( FLOOR( MOD( Diff_c * 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours "
  & TEXT( ROUND( MOD( Diff_c * 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes",
  ""
)
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for replying. I am very new to salesforce. I work with workflow as well. But i am facing difficulty . Can you kindly elaborate the process what u suggest... thanks in Advance.

Comment: Here is what we did. Our Cases have 5 statuses; New, In Process, Waiting on Customer, Waiting on Employee, and Closed. We created 5 date/time fields; "Date of New Status", "Date of In Process Status", etc. Then, we created 5 workflow rules. That criteria is "Case: Status equals Waiting on Customer" and the condition is Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria. Finally, we created an Immediate Action to update the new corresponding date/time field. In the formula part of that, enter Now().

Comment: Thank you so much ..... Its working....Through workflow rule. But there i am facing a small problem  , When i am substacting two Date/Time field it should return the time. But i only get the Number of days. Not getting the time. "LastModifiedDate-CreateDate"... Like it return only a number like 15....Created By 
Staurt Roz, 9/3/2015 7:09 AM, Last Modified By 
Staurt Roz, 9/18/2015 4:53 AM.. It returns only 15 , but not returning the min and hour........

Comment: I want to make sure that I understand what you are asking. Are you asking for a calculation that will tell you that, using your dates and times, 14 days, 21 hours, 44 minutes has passed?

Comment: This gave me a nice thing to learn myself. You can do this through something like a formula field. The following link will help you with this.    https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_examples_dates.htm   I edited the answer to include the code specifically for tracking days and time calculations.

Comment: Hi , Through workflow it is working. But the problem is suppose in our case status picklist there is 10 value. For that Case i need to create 10 different work flow rules. So i think trigger is the good option. Sir I have written a trigger. But cannot solve the error. Please see the trigger and ahelp me to solve this

Comment: What error message are you getting? I do see a couple of things that look off to me. First, you are calculating modified date and created date. So, every status change will show a longer time than the previous because the modified date will always be moving forward, while the created date will always be static. Second, you are pulling the time out for your calculation. What if your case is multiple days old? Are you taking that into consideration? Finally, you are getting the integer of your hours divided by 60,000. This rounds down to 0.

Comment: With all of that, I do need to ask. You are concerned with the number of workflow rules that you will need to calculate this. However, your trigger is going to create a new record every time the status changes on every case that you ever have. Is that what you want?